# C# Disabling functionality of holding the left mouse button after a delay (practically function like a click)

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to first off detect when the left click is being held down (MouseDown event, but not just inside the form), then after a delay of, let's say, 1 millisecond, disable all the function of left mouse button.

Put in another way, effectively make holding the button function like a one-millisecond click.

Also I want this to run at all times while the program is open, not just in the form itself but universally everywhere throughout all other programs, desktop, you name it.

Comment: Do you realize that regular human click takes longer than 1ms? Closer to 100ms. Your solution would effectively hijack the mouse.

Comment: that being said, for the sake of argument, let's forget the actual time-frame, be it 1ms or 100ms or an hour, the more important thing is the code itself. I have done some tests in some gaming programming language, and 1ms was the value i came up with, but like I said, it doesnt really matter.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811106/c-sharp-setwineventhook-fails-returns-0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.